# oracle12 c apex make rest request not working

Tags: rest, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I am trying to make a sample rest GET request to https://www.google.com via oracle APEX.

Here are the list of items I have done.

1. downloaded the certificate and added to the wallet.
   I ran the following commands

> begin DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(   host => 'google.com', 
>   ace  =>  xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('connect',
>   'resolve','http'),
>                          principal_name => 'c##test1',
>                          principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));  end;
>
> begin DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(   host => 'google.com', 
>   ace  =>  xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('connect',
>   'resolve','http'),
>                          principal_name => 'APEX_180100',
>                          principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));  end;

after this, I ran the following statement to check ACL:

> select host, lower_port, upper_port, acl from dba_host_acls;

and I get the following ACL value:

```
google.com          NETWORK_ACL_14C30EE65855448C85450D0900B07280
```

And it looks like I have recovered everything.

I found the wallet's path so I am including as a param in the request as the following:

```
select apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
    p_url => 'http://www.google.com', 
    p_http_method => 'GET',
       p_wallet_path => 'file:C:\app\Administrator\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\owm\wallets\Administrator' ,
              p_wallet_pwd => 'test123'
              )
     from dual;
```

and still getting the following errors:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1011
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1127
ORA-06512: at "APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 911
ORA-06512: at "APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1517
ORA-06512: at "APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", line 369
```

Could anyone shed some light on this issue please? I have searched and checked quite a few different posts but couldn't find the one that resolves this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is anyone interested, Got this working by doing the following:

Exported the DigiCert Global Root CA and the DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA from the site using FireFox and saved them as X509 Encoded .CRT files 
Imported the 2 DigiCert certificates ONLY with Wallet Manager, and saved the wallet.